# Replace eventListener with a function JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS, so I can't figured out how to deal with this problem:

I had two external .js files (file "Name_1", and file "Name_2"), in the file "Name 1" I have a IIFE function that adds eventListener to the window object, which is tied up with the function like this:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { //do some stuff });
```

The file "Name 1" contains simplified version of the function that triggered by this eventListener, and it should be replaced by the complete version of the function from the file "Name 2".

Basically

"Name 1" contains simplified version of the function;
"Name 2" contains complete version of the function.

Simplified version is used to cover the time gap till file "Name 2" will be executed.

Both functions in both files are wrapped in IIFE, and they both using the same event listener.

My question is - how to disable properly the first function before the second one will be applied?

For example I can remove eventListener from the window object before execution of "Name 2", but the code is still be on the page, so (as I said before - I'm new to JS) my thinking that if I execute the code from the file "Name 2" I will get TWO functions that will react on orientation chance, because of the same event listener.

How to replace:

```
$(function() {
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { 
//do some stuff 
});
});
```

to

```
$(function() {
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { 
//do some stuff
//do some stuff
//do some stuff
//do some stuff 
});
});
```

without a conflict?

Comment: This is the absolute definition of an XY Problem. What are you *really* trying to solve by having 2 files where the second should replace the first?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Jamiec - time gap

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on("orientationchange", function(ev) {
        console.log("Orientation has change", ev)
    })
});
```